# How to find most used chess openings in excel

Tags: excel, office365

I made a sheet where I put my chess games, I write if I won or lost, then I write the opening and paste the pgn code, I want to make it find all the opening names I type, and automatically copy them over to the side, and write how many times I won using them, so it should find the word "win" and then find what opening I used, and give that opening 1 point.

I tried some stuff from google but it didn't work:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Give COUNTIFS() a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you share your spreadsheet, I'd be happy to write something for you.

I imagine it would be something using COUTIFS(). So you'd count each of your named openings, and whether it's w/l. But i'm sure you'd also want to know the win percentage, not just the number, so you could divide again countif opening.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).